# What is a importance of Hive ODBC Connector

Tags: hadoop, odbc, hive

I like understand the 'Hive ODBC Connector' concept. means What is a use of Hive ODBC Connector in the architecture.

Does it require to set-up the DSN (data source Name ). Can we go for DSN-less configuration ?

Please explain in details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have one of the distributions from Cloudera, Hortonworks, MapR, Intel, Microsoft or DataStax, they already come with an ODBC driver in the distribution. The driver is created by Simba Technologies (http://www.simba.com/connectors/apache-hadoop-hive-odbc).

If you're using the Apache version of Hadoop, you can still trial the version of the ODBC driver on the above link for 30 days, however you will need to pay for it to continue use.

I only mention the above as this ODBC driver is a more complete implementation of the ODBC specification than the open source one, and it can also do SQL-HiveQL translation which essentially means that you can plug it into Excel or Tableau or the like and have them issue standard SQL. As mc110 mentioned, you can make DSN or DSN-less connections and there is also a Windows configuration dialog available should you wish to use that.

Also, in the interests of full disclosure, I work for Simba Technologies.

Answer (score 0):

As explained at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveODBC, the Hive ODBC connector implements the ODBC API for Hive, potentially allowing a lot of existing well-written ODBC applications to seamlessly use Hive as they would any other database. The link also explains what API calls are and are not supported.

SQLDriverConnect is supported, which implies you can make DSN-less connections. I suggest you read the information from the link for more information. Also, http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/Connectors/PDF/Cloudera-ODBC-Driver-for-Apache-Hive-Install-Guide.pdf has a section on configuring DSN-less authentication.